# Select string which matches following regexp

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regexp

```
/^\+[0-9]{1,3}\s[0-9]{1,6}\s[0-9\s]{5,8}$/u
```

in my PHP code. And I can't understand which strings will be matched by this expression.

I tried the following

```
+7 777 777777
```

and it does not match... could you help me to understand - what string will match this regexp?

Answer (score 3):

It does match. Perhaps there is a bug in your code? Here is the correct approach:

```
$s = '+7 777 777777';
$pattern = '/^\+[0-9]{1,3}\s[0-9]{1,6}\s[0-9\s]{5,8}$/u';
echo preg_match($pattern, $s);
```

Result:

```
1
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Gx4iu)

Comment: yes, you a right! thx! I tried to test it here (http://www.regextester.com/) and here(http://regexpal.com/) and it says "no matches". As I understand now this services works correct only with ^\+[0-9]{1,3}\s[0-9]{1,6}\s[0-9]{5,8}$ variant of regex.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but when I went to codepad.org to post an example, i got an error saying `Warning: preg_match(): Internal pcre_fullinfo() error -3 on line 4` as seen here ( http://codepad.org/tBMeMoVW ) (I did have to remove the u modifier because their php was not compiled with utf8 support, but with this simple example it shouldn't matter). Maybe if error_reporting was set to show warnings a similar error would be seen.